# (Apache Gremlin) How to dynamically create edges between all edges in a graph that share the same value in specific columns

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases

I've been tasked with creating a graph database that is going to be filled in with information from an extremely large database, as a reuslt we want to create the relationships between objects dynamically.

The labels of each Vertice aren't set in stone, but I was either going to:

- Label All Vertices as Asset

or

- Name each Vertice by what kind of asset it is (DistributionCenter, DeliveryRoute, Destination) etc.

Our data has an ID for the starting and ending location of each asset which is what links them in the current system, and this is how I would like to join them in this DB.

An example would be a Distribution Centre has a StartingNode of 0 (as it is the start point in this example) and an EndingNode of 1, with a DeliveryRoute having a StartingNode of 1 and an EndingNode of 2, e.t.c.

Does anyone know how I would generate these relationships dynamically?

I'm currently using this website to produce a demo/proof of concept:
https://gremlify.com/

Thanks for your time.
Zack

Answer (score 0):

Besides Gremlify, another great resource to use when learning Gremlin is:  https://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html

I would say that you're sort of modeling things outside of how graphs are generally modeled.  Graphs typically follow a pattern where the entities in the data are the nodes/vertices and the relationships (actions) between them are the edges.  So when you say:

> An example would be a Distribution Centre has a StartingNode of 0 (as it is the start point in this example) and an EndingNode of 1, with a DeliveryRoute having a StartingNode of 1 and an EndingNode of 2, e.t.c.

It would make more sense if a "Distribution Centre" were a node itself.  You may then have a "DeliveryRoute" edge that connects the "Distribution Centre" to some downstream destination vertex.

Something like:

```
g.addV('DistributionCentre').property(id,0).as('dc0').
    addV('DeliveryLocation').property(id,56).as('dl56').
    addE('DeliveryRoute').property(id,101).from('dc0').to('dl56').iterate()
```

The use of `as()` steps here is to supply temporary labels to components of the traversal that can be later referenced in other parts of the query.  So we're essentially creating two vertices and then later referencing those later when we create the edge between them.

But I highly suggest looking through the link referenced above as there are plenty more examples there on how to use Gremlin for this and other use cases.